# I'm getting the “Error in if (abs(x - oldx) < ftol)” after formatting data for my logit model

Tags: r, multinomial, mlogit

It had worked previously but I've been having trouble with my packages on and off throughout the day, although maybe that has nothing to do with it. I had ran the code below earlier and it had worked. But for the past few hours I keep on getting the same error

> “Error in if (abs(x - oldx) < ftol) { :    missing value where
>   TRUE/FALSE needed”

I'm trying to run a logit model without alternative specific constants (although I keep getting the same error regardless of the coefficients I'm trying to generate):

```
H<-mlogit.data(heat, choice="depvar", shape = "long",alt.levels=c("ec","er","gc","hp"))

m1<-mlogit(depvar ~ -1 + ic +gr + er +hp, H)
summary(m1)
```

I'd appreciate any pointers, thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It was a syntax error when formatting the dataset...I was missing one of my alternate values and I suppose when I tried to execute the logit model it was reading rows of empty values it couldn't recognize...